# Pointer being freed was not allocated?

Tags: c++, pointers

Tell me what the 3rd line is doing please.

```
int main(){

int *p = new int[3];

*p++=0; // What's this line doing?

delete p;

return 0;   
}
```

Comment: You should be more concerned about the line that follows that one.

Comment: What's it doing? It is invoking the dreaded undefined behavior. Prepare for a high risk of nasal demons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*p++=0;` means this:

1. Write `sizeof(int)` zero bytes to an address stored in `p`.
2. Increment the value of `p` by `sizeof(int)`.

In other words — you have incremented the pointer and what you then passing to `delete` is not the same as was returned by operator `new[]`.

As @FredLarson has also mentioned, you have to use `delete [] p;` in order to delete an array.

Also, I'd recommend you read up on pointers, pointer arithmetics and pre-/post-increment. Pick a book from our [Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: And even if the pointer value were correct, it should be `delete [] p;`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And you are right. I don't understand the sequence of increment and assign here...

Comment: Well, now you went that far. 8v) I'm off to bed myself.

Comment: @Arch1tect: This is post-increment. It means — increment after using the variable. So the increment is guaranteed to happen __after__ dereferencing.

Comment: @VladLazarenko totally undertand now. Thank you so much and every one else. :)

Answer (score 1):

The first element in the array is set to 0 and p is advanced by one to point to the second element.

```
delete p; // this has undefined behaviour
```

Use `delete [] p;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting p[0] to 0 and advancing the pointer to p[1]. What are you trying to do?